# Fastest way to search a collection of objects, by field

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I was wondering if there is a faster way to do this:

I have an array of objects.  When presented with a new object, I want to determine if that object already exists in the array (by using a fields in the object).  If it exists, simply append one of the fields.  If it does not exists, add it.

Here is my code:

```
If (myCollection.count <= 0) Then
        'collection must be empty, so just add it
        Set myObj= New objClass
        With myObj
            .OBJ_ID = ID
            .first_name = first_name
            .last_name = last_name
            .page_number = pageCounter 'some global variable
        End With
        myCollection.Add myObj, ID
    Else        
        Dim myObj As objClass
        'iterate through collection and see if it already exists
        For Each myObj In myCollection
            'if it does exists, just append one of the fields
            If myObj.OBJ_ID = ID Then
                myObj.page_number = myObj.page_number & "," & pageCounter
                isFound= True
            End If
        Next
        'if it doesn't exists, add it
        If (isFound = False) Then
            Set myObj= New objClass
            With myObj
                .OBJ_ID = ID
                .first_name = first_name
                .last_name = last_name
                .page_number = pageCounter
            End With
            myCollection.Add myObj
        End If
    End If
```

So, I guess the part that needs to be optimized is iterating over the whole collection to see if an object, with a given field value, already exists.

thanks

Comment: An array of `Object` or a `Collection` of `Object`?

Comment: It is a collection of objects.  My bad, I'll edit the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

substitute

```
For Each myObj In myCollection
    'if it does exists, just append one of the fields
    If myObj.OBJ_ID = ID Then
        myObj.page_number = myObj.page_number & "," & pageCounter
        isFound = True
    End If
Next
```

with

```
On Error Resume Next
Set myObj = myCollection(ID)
On Error GoTo 0
If Not myObj Is Nothing Then
    myObj.page_number = myObj.page_number & "," & pageCounter
    isFound = True
End If
```

it's faster to try and set a possible collection item then iterating through all of them

Comment: Thanks, this did help to speed things up.